# este juego esta lanzando la funcion de perder erroneamente, como lo corrijo?

Tags: javascript

es un juego de memoria tipo simon, eventlisteners reciben los clicks del usuario despues de que una secuencia de cambios de background en diferentes divs aparece simulando estar iluminados,
ahora el comportamiento esperado es que compare si el usuario clickeo o no el div que se ilumino en su correcto orden  esto pasa en la funcion elegirColor(ev), si se eligio correctamente se vuelve a empezar la secuencia añadiendo 1 div ilumiando mas hasta que se llega al nivel maximo de numeros en el array de base para el orden d ela secuencia donde aparece un aviso de se gana y se puede reiniciar el juego, tambien si se elige erroneamente ne algun punto aparece aviso de perder y se puede reiniciar el juego.
ahora el problema es que en la primera ronda de juego en algun punto (cuando la secuencia se puede iluminar 3-4 veces se dispara el aviso de que se perdio aunque se haya elegido correctamente, igual al reinicar el juego sucede lo mismo desde la primera peticion de interaccion con el usuario se registra como erronea la eleccion, supongo que el error se encuentra en la funcion elegirColor

```
>  <script>

const boton = document.getElementById('btnEmpezar')

const verde = document.getElementById('verde')
const amarillo =  document.getElementById('amarillo')
const azul = document.getElementById('azul')
const rojo = document.getElementById('rojo')
const blanco = document.getElementById('blanco')

const box1 = document.getElementById('box1')
const box2 = document.getElementById('box2')
const box3 = document.getElementById('box3')
const box4 = document.getElementById('box4')



const loser = document.getElementById('loser')
const winner = document.getElementById('winner')

let level = 0
const ULTIMO_NIVEL = 5
let subnivel = 0
const colores = {
    verde, 
    amarillo,
    azul,
    rojo,
    blanco, 
    box1, 
    box2, 
    box3, 
    box4
};
let timeoutIluminacion = null;

let secuencia = new Array(10).fill(0).map(n => Math.floor(Math.random() * 9))


const nota1= document.getElementById('audio1')
const nota2= document.getElementById('audio2')
const nota3= document.getElementById('audio3')
const nota4= document.getElementById('audio4')
const nota5= document.getElementById('audio5')
const nota6= document.getElementById('audio6')
const nota7= document.getElementById('audio7')
const nota8= document.getElementById('audio8')
const nota9= document.getElementById('audio9')

function tocarNota(color){
      switch (color) { 
        case 'rojo': 
         return nota1.play()
         case 'verde':
            return nota1.play()
        case 'amarillo':
            return nota2.play()
        case 'azul':
            return nota3.play()
        case 'blanco':
            return nota5.play()
            case 'box1':
            return nota6.play()
        case 'box2':
            return nota7.play()
        case 'box3':
            return nota8.play()
        case 'box4':
            return nota9.play()
        

      }
}


function hideButton(){
    boton.classList.add('hide')
   setTimeout( iluminarSecuencia, 500)
}


function  iluminarSecuencia() {
    for (let i = 0; i <= level; i++) {
        const color = transformarNumeroAColor(secuencia[i])
        setTimeout(() => iluminarColor(color), 1400 * i)
        console.log(color)
    }
    agregarEventosClick()
}

function iluminarColor(color) {
    colores[color].classList.add('light')
    tocarNota(color)
    setTimeout(() => this.apagarColor(color), 350)
}

function apagarColor(color) {
    colores[color].classList.remove('light')
}

function transformarNumeroAColor(numero) {
    switch (numero) {
        case 0:
            return 'rojo'
        case 1:
            return 'verde'
        case 2:
            return 'amarillo'
        case 3:
            return 'azul'
        case 4:
            return 'blanco'
        case 5:
            return 'box1'
        case 6:
            return 'box2'
        case 7:
            return 'box3'
        case 8:
            return 'box4'
        
    }
}

function transformarColorANumero(color) {
    switch (color) {
        case 'rojo':
            return 0
        case 'verde':
            return 1
        case 'amarillo':
            return 2
        case 'azul':
            return 3
        case 'blanco':
            return 4
        
       case 'box1':
            return 5
        case 'box2':
            return 6
        case 'box3':
            return 7
        case 'box4':
            return 8
        
    }
}

function agregarEventosClick() {
    colores.verde.addEventListener('click', this.elegirColor)
    colores.amarillo.addEventListener('click', this.elegirColor)
    colores.rojo.addEventListener('click', this.elegirColor)
    colores.azul.addEventListener('click', this.elegirColor)
    colores.blanco.addEventListener('click', this.elegirColor)

    colores.box1.addEventListener('click', this.elegirColor)
    colores.box2.addEventListener('click', this.elegirColor)
    colores.box3.addEventListener('click', this.elegirColor)
    colores.box4.addEventListener('click', this.elegirColor)
    
}

function eliminarEventosClick() {
    colores.verde.removeEventListener('click', this.elegirColor)
    colores.amarillo.removeEventListener('click', this.elegirColor)
    colores.rojo.removeEventListener('click', this.elegirColor)
    colores.azul.removeEventListener('click', this.elegirColor)
    colores.blanco.removeEventListener('click', this.elegirColor)

    colores.box1.removeEventListener('click', this.elegirColor)
    colores.box2.removeEventListener('click', this.elegirColor)
    colores.box3.removeEventListener('click', this.elegirColor)
    colores.box4.removeEventListener('click', this.elegirColor)
    
}

function  elegirColor(ev) {
    const nombreColor = ev.target.dataset.color
    const numeroColor = transformarColorANumero(nombreColor)
    iluminarColor(nombreColor)
    if (numeroColor === secuencia[subnivel]) {
        subnivel++

        if (subnivel > level) {
            eliminarEventosClick()
            level++
            subnivel=0

            timeoutIluminacion = setTimeout(iluminarSecuencia, 1500)
        }
        if (level === (ULTIMO_NIVEL + 1)) {
            ganoJuego()
            clearTimeout(timeoutIluminacion);
        } 
    }
    else {
        perdioJuego()
    }
} 




function ganoJuego(){
    eliminarEventosClick();
    winner.classList.remove('hide');
    
    setTimeout(start, 1000);
}

function start(){
 
    winner.classList.add('hide')
    boton.classList.remove('hide')
    level=0
}

function perdioJuego(){
  eliminarEventosClick()
 
   
    loser.classList.remove('hide')
    setTimeout(startos, 1000)
}

function startos(){
    loser.classList.add('hide')
    boton.classList.remove('hide')
    level=0 
}




function secuenciaFinal(){
  for(let i=0; i < 4; i++ ){
    setTimeout(iluminarSecuenciaFinal, 1000 * i)
  }
}


function iluminarSecuenciaFinal(){
  colores.amarillo.classList.add('light')
  colores.verde.classList.add('light')
  colores.rojo.classList.add('light')
  colores.azul.classList.add('light')

  setTimeout(apagarSecuenciaFinal, 500)

}

function apagarSecuenciaFinal(){
  colores.amarillo.classList.remove('light')
  colores.rojo.classList.remove('light')
  colores.verde.classList.remove('light')
  colores.azul.classList.remove('light')

  iluminarSecuenciaFinal2()
}

function iluminarSecuenciaFinal2(){
    colores.box1.classList.add('light')
  colores.box2.classList.add('light')
  colores.box3.classList.add('light')
  colores.box4.classList.add('light')
  setTimeout(apagarSecuenciaFinal2, 500)
  }

  function apagarSecuenciaFinal2(){
    colores.box1.classList.remove('light')
  colores.box2.classList.remove('light')
  colores.box3.classList.remove('light')
  colores.box4.classList.remove('light')

  }


  </script>


> <style>

  body{
    margin: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
.gameboard{
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 260px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 5%;
  position: relative;
  
}
.polen{
  position: absolute;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  top: calc(0% - 50px);
             left: calc(-20% - 200px);
  
}

.box{
 box-sizing: border-box;
  
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px  solid black ;
  display: flex;
 margin: 0;
 border-radius: 5%;
}
.uno{
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 223, 0.767);
  position: relative;
}

.uno.light{
  background-color: rgba(129, 129, 252, 0.767);
}

.dos{
  background-color:  rgb(49, 122, 55);
  
}
.dos.light{
  background-color:  rgb(102, 126, 104);
}

.tres{
  background-color: rgb(198, 209, 43) ;
  position: relative;
}

.tres.light{
  background-color: rgb(209, 212, 156) ;
}

.cuatro{
  background-color: rgb(177, 12, 12);
}

.cuatro.light{
  background-color: rgb(196, 111, 111);
}

.petado{
  width: 130px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  background-color: rgb(252, 255, 55);
  display: flex;
  align-self: flex-end;
  border-top-left-radius: 60%;
  border-bottom-right-radius:50% ;


}

.petado.light{
  background-color: rgb(252, 253, 201);
  
}

.petado.dark{
  background-color:rgb(195, 197, 48);
}

.petaun{
  width: 130px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  display: flex;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50% ;
  border-top-right-radius: 60%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  position: absolute;
   bottom:0;
   right:0;

}

.petaun.light{
  background-color: rgb(255, 129, 129);
}


.petaun.dark{
  background-color: rgb(177, 0, 0);
}

.petatre{
  width: 130px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  background-color: rgb(79, 255, 88);
  border-bottom-right-radius: 60%;
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
}

.petatre.light{
  background-color: rgb(198, 253, 201);
}


.petatre.dark{
  background-color: rgb(67, 204, 74);
}

.petacua{
  width: 130px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  display: flex;
  background-color: blue;
  border-bottom-left-radius:60% ;
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;

}

.petacua.light{
  background-color: rgb(138, 138, 255);
  
}

.petacua.dark{
  background-color:rgb(0, 0, 211);
}

.polen{
  position:absolute;
  border: 10px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  top: calc(50% - 33px);
  
  left:calc(50% - 33px);

}

.polen.light{
  background-color: rgb(133, 127, 127)
  
}

.polen.dark{
  background-color:rgb(207, 205, 205);
}

 

.boton{
  
  position:absolute;
  border: 5px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  color: aliceblue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgb(27, 26, 26);
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  top: calc(50% - 31px);
  
  left:calc(50% - 30px);
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: right;
}

.boton.hide{
  display: none;
 
 
}

.boton:hover{

  border: 1px solid rgb(10, 10, 10);

  text-decoration: underline;
  font-style: italic;
}
.boton:focus{
  outline:0;
}


.resultado{
 
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  border-radius: 5%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 55px;
  background-color: black;
  font-family: monospace;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;

}

.resultados{
 
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  border-radius: 5%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 55px;
  background-color: black;
  font-family: monospace;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;

}

 .resultado.hide{
  display: none;
} 

.resultados.hide{
  display: none;
} 



</style>

</head>
<body>
  <div class="gameboard">
    <div class="box uno " id="box1" data-color="box1">
      <div id='rojo' class="petaun" data-color="rojo" ></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box dos " id="box2" data-color="box2">
      <div id="amarillo" class="petado" data-color="amarillo"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box tres " id="box3" data-color="box3">
      <div id="verde" class="petatre" data-color="verde"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box cuatro " id="box4"   data-color="box4">
      <div id="azul" class="petacua" data-color="azul"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="blanco" class="polen" data-color="blanco"></div>
    <button id="btnEmpezar" class="boton" onclick="hideButton()">Empezar!</button>
    
    <div id="winner" class="resultado hide"><p>Ganaste!
      :)
    </p></div>
    <div id="loser" class="resultados hide"><p> :( <br /> Perdiste!
      
    </p></div>
  </div>

  <audio src="./notas/nota1.mp3" id="audio1" preload="auto"></audio>
  <audio src="./notas/nota2.mp3" id="audio2" preload="auto"></audio>
  <audio src="./notas/nota3.mp3" id="audio3" preload="auto"></audio>
  <audio src="./notas/nota4.mp3" id="audio4" preload="auto"></audio>

  <audio src="./notas/nota5.mp3" id="audio5" preload="auto"></audio>
  <audio src="./notas/nota6.mp3" id="audio6" preload="auto"></audio>
  <audio src="./notas/nota7.mp3" id="audio7" preload="auto"></audio>
  <audio src="./notas/nota8.mp3" id="audio8" preload="auto"></audio>
  <audio src="./notas/nota9.mp3" id="audio9" preload="auto"></audio>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Siempre será mejor no incluir basura en las preguntas. Si la validación dice que le gastes un poco más a explicar, es por tu propio bien (para que los demás podamos entender mejor y responder mejor)

Comment: El problema aca es.. en donde de toda esta pared de codigo esta el problema? donde llenas el array que hay que replicar? donde lo comprobas? todo el resto, sobra...

Comment: en la funcion  elegirColor(ev) se comprueba let secuencia